# Variable for array index

Tags: php

The only thing i thought of was this trying to make this code work:

```
$index = [$player]['matchHistory'][$matchIndex];
$players . $index . ['platformId'];
```

Trying to get this final outcome

```
$players[$playerIndex]['matchHistory'][$matchIndex]['platformId'];
```

But with this code, i get this error

```
Fatal error: Assignments can only happen to writable values in C:\Users\elvarp\Documents\webdev\iceleague\testing.php on line 39
```

Is this possible in php? Don't have enough knowledge to google this around.

EDIT: Full code i'm working with:

```
foreach ($players as $playerIndex => $player) {
  $matchHistory = $api->getRecentMatchList($player['summonerAccountId'], "season=9");
  foreach ($matchHistory['matches'] as $matchIndex => $match) {
    $index = [$playerIndex]['matchHistory'][$matchIndex];
    $players . $index . ['platformId'] = $match['platformId'];
    $players . $index . ['matchId'] = $match['gameId'];
    $players . $index . ['championId'] = $match['champion'];
    $players . $index . ['queue'] = $match['queue'];
    $players . $index . ['season'] = $match['season'];
    $players . $index . ['timestamp'] = $match['timestamp'];
    $players . $index . ['role'] = $match['role'];
    $players . $index . ['lane'] = $match['lane'];
  }
}
```

The value of $player

```
Array
(
    [summonerName] => Retro
    [summonerId] => 27467980
    [summonerAccountId] => 31905356
)
```

Comment: Which line is your error ? This : `$players . $index . ['platformId'];` ?

Comment: can you show values of `$player,$matchIndex,$playerIndex`?

Comment: Sorry forgot to put in the line which gives me the error.

This is it.

       `$players . $index . ['platformId'] = $match['platformId'];`

Comment: I edited the post to show the full code i'm working with.

Comment: Uhm… how about just `$players[$playerIndex]['matchHistory'][$matchIndex] = $match;`…? There appears to be little point in you assigning each key in `$match` to `$players` manually. If you simply assign the whole array at once, your problem disappears entirely.

Comment: Otherwise you'd simply work with a reference: `$playerMatch = &$players[$playerIndex]['matchHistory'][$matchIndex]; $playerMatch['platformId'] = ...;`

Comment: I thought i had to assign each key in $match to $players, Thanks for showing me i could save the whole $match to $players, It's much better for this project.